# Unable to find uri[model://model:://sun]

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've just started learning ROS and GAZEBO. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.4, ROS Lunar and Gazebo 7.

The following world:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sdf version="1.4">
    <world name="myworld">
        <include>
            <uri>model://model:://sun</uri>
        </include>
        
        <include>
            <uri>model://model:://ground_plane</uri>
        </include>
    </world>
</sdf>
```

Throws these errors:

```
Error [parser.cc:581] Unable to find uri[model://model:://sun]
Error [parser.cc:581] Unable to find uri[model://model:://ground_plane]
```

Both models are in ~/.gazebo/models/.

I have also tried this world file:

```
<sdf version="1.4">
    <world name="myworld">
        <include>
            <uri>model:://sun</uri>
        </include>
        
        <include>
            <uri>model:://ground_plane</uri>
        </include>
    </world>
</sdf>
```

Getting the same error.

Do I need to do anything else? Like adding the GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH env var into the world file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19962/unable-to-find-uri%5Bmodel://model:://sun%5D/) by [VansFannel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4697/vansfannel/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The correct syntax is: `<uri>model://sun</uri>`

---

Originally posted by [Raskkii](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4131/raskkii/) with karma: 376 on 2018-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1